# What's the best method to send notifications at specific time through android app?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-notifications

So far I have tried alarm manager which works fine for devices with stock android but creats complications for devices such as One plus, Xiomi etc. 
Is there any other way to send notifications on specific times?

Comment: You can use FireBase Push Notifications

Comment: I want user the receive the notification from within the app (like reminders) at certain times regardless of him being connected to internet.

Answer (score 0):

I use a service to send and update my notifications. In it, I use these code to build a timer

```
final long period = 5000;
        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // do your task here
                getData();
            }
        }, 0, period);
```

The method `getData()` checks for data and shows notification with `NotificationManager`

Comment: I need to receive notifications even when the app is closed.

Comment: Thats why you use a service. Service runs even when the app is closed, although it restarts.